# Google Analytics - parse Event Label value

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to parse Even label string and create a report from it in GA?

When recording an `Event` in Google Analytics, the platform allows you to put any string in the `Label` field - for example a stringified JSON object:

```
{
  "searchField": "value1",
  "searchCategory": "value2",
  "searchToken": "value3"
}
```

Due to the structure of the data, using the `Event Action` for grouping is not feasible and the object can have more data inside.

Is there any way to create a report in GA that parses that data and uses the value in the JSON (for example create a table with all event labels having 3 columns: `searchField`, `searchCategory` and `searchToken`).

If the above is not possible is there any alternative way to record custom data and report on it in GA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the reported value on-the-fly in the interface.

You can manipulate the value before it is stored by using a filter (currently not an option in GA4), but that will treat the value as a string; you cannot parse it as JSON in a filter. To store it you would need to create a filter for each value that you want to extract from the JSON, and then copy the value to a dimension (probably some custom dimension created for the task). I  imagine this will be a quite annoying task.

You can create your reports in Data Studio and extract values there. Again, this is a regex matching a string, not a JSON operation (I searched for a quick example, so [here is one](https://thomasgerstmann.de/google-data-studio-extract-json-regexpextract/)).

If you are using GA4, you can export the fields from BigQuery and turn them into JSON and parse them, but at that point this has nothing to do anymore with the GA interface.

So you cannot parse JSON on the fly in GA reports. If you plan to extract values with a regex from a string before it is stored in your view, then it is possible, but stringified JSON is not a particularly good choice. If that is what you are stuck with, I recommend you report via Data Studio.

Comment: Although the question was closed as off-topic this answers it perfectly answering the question. Data Studio does support what I am looking for and allows to parse value using regex as you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: Well, reporting might be considered off-topic, but then parsing JSON isn't, so there might be different opinions on that (and voting/closing is a bit erratic on GA/GTM questions in any case). Anyway, glad I could help.